# How to navigate push view controller from UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, navigationcontroller

How to navigate PushViewController from UIView class to New View Controller, Till now what I tried with delegate/ protocol but still no success from button click, below is the swift code what I tried to navigate from uiview class

```
protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func didTapButton()
}

class Ticket : UIView {
    
    static let instance = Ticket()
    
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketView: UIView!
    var delegate : MyViewDelegate?

        
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Ticket", owner: self, options: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnHistoryTicket(_ sender: ThemeButtonTicket) {
    }
    @IBAction func btnNewTicket(_ sender: ThemeButtonTicket) {
        func buttonTapAction() {
            delegate?.didTapButton() // Expect to navigate
        }
        
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func showTicket(){
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first{$0.isKeyWindow}?.addSubview(parentView)
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ticket = Ticket()
        ticket.delegate = self
        
    }

    func didTapButton() {
        let vc = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubmitTicketVC") as! SubmitTicketVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: i think it happens because there is no `navigationController` were added in storyboard / Programatically.

Comment: first let me know `present` will work or not?

Comment: Check if `self.navigationController?` is not nil.

Comment: @RB's I also try with `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` but not working

Comment: sorry i didn't see that's `UIView` class not `UIViewController`.

Comment: @Kudos In Debug it's not going inside the function in btnNewTicket

Comment: here you need to work with work with Notification add observer and post.

Comment: I got mistake. Delete func buttonTapAction() {} insite your btnNewTicket. You cant define func inside action func.

Comment: USe this code:-  `@IBAction func btnNewTicket(_ sender: ThemeButtonTicket) {
            delegate?.didTapButton() // Expect to navigate
        
    }`

Comment: @Kudos It's not working

Comment: is it still not going in btnNewTicket button?

Comment: @Kudos Not going

Comment: Your `ViewController` doesn't hold any reference of the Ticket view. I assume that Ticket view is displayed using the storyboard, if so you should have an @IBOutlet in the view controller, referencing the Ticket view (instead of creating it manually). You should also remove the `buttonTapAction` function and call directly `delegate?.didTapButton()` in `btnNewTicket`

Comment: Have you tried removing the nested function buttonTapAction, and simply try to delegate?

Comment: @MohammedNabil - edit your question and include the necessary information. In the code you posted for `ViewController`, you have created an instance of `Ticket()` but you haven't added it to your view. If you added it in Storyboard, then you need to assign it to an `@IBOutlet` and set the delegate on **that** instance, not on a new one.